# C++: Linking extern variables from within a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, linker, constants, extern

I can't seem to reference an externally-defined variable from within a namespace using `extern`.  It works from the global scope, but as soon as a namespace is thrown in there,  it fails to link.

My constants file looks like:

`StringConstants.cpp`

```
#include "MyString.h"

MyString test1("string1");

MyString test2("string2");
```

The main program looks like this:

`main.cpp`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "MyString.h"

extern MyString test1;

namespace {
    extern MyString test2;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%s\n", test1.Str());
    printf("%s\n", test2.Str());
}
```

I get similar errors in both GCC and Visual Studio:

```
gcc    main.o StringConstants.o   -o main
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `(anonymous namespace)::test2'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

1>Linking...
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class MyString `anonymous namespace'::test2" (?test2@?A0x0df4aa01@@3VMyString@@A)
1>C:\p4\namespace_repro\namespace_repro2\Debug\namespace_repro2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I tried qualifying the reference to test2 (`extern MyString ::test2`), but it just thinks that test2 is a static member of MyString.  A named namespace doesn't behave differently than an anonymous one.  For various reasons, we don't want to remove namespaces or put the externs outside of the namespaces.

Here's the other files, for completeness:

`MyString.h`

```
class MyString {
public:
   MyString(const char* str): mStr(str) {};
   const char* Str() const { return mStr; }
private:
   const char* mStr; 
};
```

`Makefile`

```
CC=gcc 
CFLAGS=-Wall

main: StringConstants.o main.o
```

The goals for this system are that the constants all be defined in one file, and that they be resolved at link time rather than being in a header.  It seemed like the above code would work, but since it's rejected by two different linkers it seems my understanding of C++ is not good enough.  Advice on how to get this to work, other than putting the externs outside of the namespaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> $7.3.1/2 - "Every name first declared
>   in a namespace is a member of that
>   namespace."

This means that the name 'test2' is part of the anonymous namespace and should be defined in that namespace if it is used.

It is not an issue with the anonymous namespace alone but for that matter any namespace.

Comment: *sigh* I guess I can't disagree with the spec.  I looked at that section a number of times, but didn't parse the meaning of that particular line.  Thanks for spelling it out.

Answer (score 5):

What...

```
namespace { 
    extern MyString test2; 
}
```

...does is say test2 should exist in an anonymous namespace, but it doesn't - it's in the global namespace.  You've lied to your compiler, therefore it generates an object that won't link.  You need the extern declaration to be made from the same namespace scope as the variable.

BUT, there should be a StringConstants.h, which main.cpp should include, such that the compilation unit knows about the strings without any further statements.

Comment: +1, the anonymous namespace is the culprit here. Note that he will still need to use extern, whether it's in a header or not.

Comment: The problem with having a StringConstants.h is that it'll basically necessitate recompiling every file in the program when someone modifies or adds a constant (which will be pretty common).  Is there any way to tell the compiler that I want to refer to a global test2?

Comment: @breath: if things are that volatile, not having a shared header will be a lot worse: what happens when someone realises some value should be changed from int to double?  Programs keep building and linking and failing at run time.  If the shared headers really too hard, then consider splitting it up with separate headers for any volatile parts that fewer translation units need.  Consider pImpl, Interfaces and other abstractions that help decouple clients from implementation.

Comment: Well, they're all string constants, so no one's going to be changing any types.  We're OK with missing constants resulting in linker errors.  A more feasible solution for us is to simply move the extern declarations outside of namespaces in the source files, or to simply rip out all of our namespaces and just go commando as it were, but neither seems like a satisfactory option.  If it can't otherwise be done, it can't be done, but it really seems like something that should be possible.  :)

Comment: @breath: Consider `<iosfwd>` - it provides forward declarations for classes in `<iostream>`, yet is maintained alongside it (and ideally - especially in a volatile software system - would be included from it to ensure consistency). Could you not do the same: have extra extern-declaration headers for each client app / translation-unit logically "under" the "all-strings" header, with the latter including them to check consistency...?

Comment: We could, but we're not ever really going to be changing the values of the string constants, only their membership, so most of the time we'd still be recompiling entire modules.  :(  I think that simply putting the externs outside of the namespaces, while unattractive, at least limits recompilation only to the modified .cpp.

Comment: I appreciate your help, Tony, sorry that our use case is so different from the norm.

Comment: @breath: no worries... the right answer's always the one that works best in the circumstances.  Cheers.